# Filtering out elements in RoseTree

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function `filterTree` that would filter out elements in RoseTree using given condition:

```
data RoseTree a = RoseTree a [RoseTree a]
                   deriving (Show, Functor)

extractChild :: RoseTree a -> RoseTree a
extractChild (RoseTree _ (x:[])) = x
extractChild rTree = rTree

filterTree :: ( a -> Bool ) -> RoseTree a -> RoseTree a
filterTree condition rTree@(RoseTree a list) = 
    if (condition $ a) 
      then (extractChild rTree)  
      else (RoseTree a (filterTreeList condition list)) 

filterTreeList :: (a -> Bool) -> [RoseTree a] -> [RoseTree a]
filterTreeList condition [] = []
filterTreeList condition (x:xs) = [filterTree condition x] ++ (filterTreeList condition xs)
```

But it does not work quite as expected. For some reason it does not filter out nested elements that satisfy the condition. For example, if I run

```
filterTree (==2) (RoseTree 1 [ RoseTree 2 [ RoseTree 3 [] ]])
```

then it runs fine returning `RoseTree 1 [RoseTree 3 []]`. But if I run it with one more nested element that satisfies the condition

```
filterTree (==2) (RoseTree 1 [ RoseTree 2 [ RoseTree 3 [RoseTree 2 [RoseTree 1[]]] ]])
```

then it returns erroneous result having second matching element in the list: `RoseTree 1 [RoseTree 3 [RoseTree 2 [RoseTree 1 []]]]`

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: To be clear on the intended semantics: if a node satisfies the removal condition, you promote all of its children up (and then also try removing them)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: Then what happens if the root satisfies the condition?

Comment: All its children will be moved up

Comment: I must not be clear: by "move up" I mean raise the children to be at the same level as their parent was previously. The problem is that the root has no parent list to which its children should be moved up. What would be the new root?

Comment: Aha, I see what you mean. Good question, I don't know :)

Comment: Shouldn't there be additional filtering going on in this case: `then (extractChild rTree)`?

Comment: @JamesWilcox: I tried that. If I do `then (extractChild $ filterTree condition rTree)` or `then (filterTree condition $ extractChild rTree)`, it causes infinite loop.

Comment: Well yeah, the first one obviously loops. The second one also loops because `extractChild` sometimes doesn't do anything. I don't really understand why `extractChild` is defined the way it is. It means that if there's not exactly one child, then nothing gets removed?

Comment: @JamesWilcox: Yes, that's correct. Generally for RoseTree, if there is more than one child, then it is not clear where to assign them after deletion of parent. In my case doing transfer of only one child makes sense because of the nature of data I want to use it with. It always contains only single child in the place where parent is to be removed due to matching condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me on the examples you provided.

Note that it will loop if a node ever matches the filter condition and does not have exactly one child.

```
filterTree :: ( a -> Bool ) -> RoseTree a -> RoseTree a
filterTree condition rTree@(RoseTree a list) = 
    if (condition $ a) 
      then filterTree condition (extractChild rTree)
      else (RoseTree a (filterTreeList condition list))
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't specified in the previous comment that my data structure *can* have more than one child. It is just that *removed* elements (matching condition) in my data structure have only one child. I should probably update the question with more details...

Comment: @altern I believe this solution still works in that case. If not, can you give another example input that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: If I do `filterTree (==2) (RoseTree 1 [ RoseTree 2 [ RoseTree 4 [], RoseTree 3 [ RoseTree 2 [RoseTree 1[]]] ]])` with your solution, it goes into infinite loop.

Comment: @altern But that violates your precondition that all nodes matching the filter condition will have exactly one child. The first matching node has two children.

Comment: I had a small hiccup with something else that prevented me from validating your solution. Found an error in my program that incorrectly matched an element that does not have children. Given that error is fixed, your solution seems to work, thanks!